# Python 3: Selecting random pair elements from a numpy array without repetition

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random, repeat

I want to select random pair elements from a population array in each loop without repetition.

In my code, I create a population array then I pass it to the selection function where I will generate two random index numbers in each loop, and based on it I will select the pair elements from the population array.
so if I have a population size 5, then my result size will be 10, because in each loop I will get two elements.

```
import random
import numpy as np
population_size = 5
dimension= 2
upper = 1
lower = 0
pair_loop = 1
pair_size = 2 

def select (pop
    parents = np.zeros((0, dimension), dtype=np.float_)

    for i in range (population_size):

        for ii in range (pair_loop): 

            random_index= np.random.randint (population_size, size=(pair_size))
            parents = np.vstack((parents, population[random_index,]))
            print (i ,"random_index", random_index)
            print (parents)

    return (parents)

population = np.random.choice(np.linspace(lower, upper, 10), size=(population_size,dimension), replace=True)    
parents = select(population)
```

I want to get two different elements, where I don't want to repeat the same index number,

for example, if I have: [2, 4]
I don't want to see the:  [2, 4] or [4,2] again

Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: You may need to give a more specific example, since the answers make different assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of indices with:

```
import itertools, random
def select(size, pair_size):
    g =itertools.combinations(range(size),pair_size)
    alist = list(g)
    random.shuffle(alist)
    return alist

In [42]: alist = select(5,2)
In [43]: alist
Out[43]: 
[(0, 3),
 (1, 3),
 (2, 3),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 4),
 (3, 4),
 (0, 1),
 (2, 4),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 4)]
```

And apply it to your population:

```
In [44]: population = np.random.choice(np.arange(10,20), size=(5,2), replace=Tru
    ...: e)  
In [45]: population
Out[45]: 
array([[18, 19],
       [16, 17],
       [10, 11],
       [10, 15],
       [14, 15]])
In [46]: population[alist,]
Out[46]: 
array([[[18, 19],
        [10, 15]],

       [[16, 17],
        [10, 15]],

       [[10, 11],
        [10, 15]],

       [[18, 19],
        [10, 11]],

       [[18, 19],
        [14, 15]],

       [[10, 15],
        [14, 15]],

       [[18, 19],
        [16, 17]],

       [[10, 11],
        [14, 15]],

       [[16, 17],
        [10, 11]],

       [[16, 17],
        [14, 15]]])
```

Comment: thank you, this great way but what if I need just one pair or two pairs by random, not all possible pairs?  `g =itertools.combinations(range(size),pair_size)` here I have the `range` and the `pair_size` can I add also how many pairs I need by randoms? @hpaulj

Comment: You could try `np.random.choose` from `list(g)`. I don't think that's an improvement over `shuffle`.  You can't make a random selection from the generator directly.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicates generate the entire index set, shuffle it, and pop pairs of index values from the shuffled set.  For example:

```
import random

def pair_generator(population_size):
    pop_range = 2 * population_size
    population = [i for i in range(1, pop_range + 1)]
    random.shuffle(population)
    for _ in range(population_size):
        yield [population.pop(), population.pop()]

population_size = 5
print([pair for pair in pair_generator(population_size)])
```

This is generator-based, so you can generate as few or as many pairs as you wish, up to the entire set.

Comment: But I only get 5 items from your generator; the OP apparently expects 10.

Comment: @hpaulj OP asked how to get unique pairings, this demos that.   Bump `population_size` to any value you like.